# Can you desalinate or distill water with a Peltier module?

Tags: solar-energy, peltier, cooling, water, heater

Can you use both sides of a Peltier module to distill water? Using one side for heating and the other side for cooling. If so what type of Peltier module do you need and can you make it solar powered? Also do you need heatsinks, and how should it be placed? Do you need anything else besides the module? What type of power supply do you need?

Comment: What is the latent heat of vaporization of water? What power output does your peltier unit have?

Comment: I'd say the answer to all of the above is yes, you can.  The devil is in the details.  You need to rough out some system specs.  How much water output do you need?  How big do you want your system to be? Does it need to run when there's no sun?  What pumps and valves do you need and what are their power requirements?

Comment: While technically feasible, this would be far more efficiently done as a [solar desalinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_desalination).

Comment: Or a reverse osmosis desalinator.

Comment: Welcome. That is a lot of questions. Perhaps you should consider pre-made equipment. This is too big a project with sometimes high voltages to be a simple hobby project.

Comment: You need to boil water for desalination, peltiers are inefficient heaters and coolers.

Comment: The temperature difference is only a few degrees,  peltiers work well in that zone.

Answer (score 1):

solar panels are about 20% efficient, while thermal collectors are about 60% efficient. unless you can get a energy efficiency ratio 3 from the peltier you'll get better performance by just using the sun's heat directky to evaporate the water.

Admittedly the termerature difference between the condenser and the boiler will be fairly small so a high efficiencty may be possible, but peltiers have a failry high electrical resistance so the large current needed to move the large amount of heat will require a large peltier device to minimise the resistive losses.